# Module is present, but it says it isn't found

Tags: python-3.x, module, compiler-errors

I am running into a ModuleNotFoundError in my development environment.

I am running Atom and the module is 100% present.

The structure is as follows:

I am executing some code in file-one.py which is calling a sub directory and executing a file which uses a function from another file in the same folder.

I am getting an error from the file (in the subdirectory referencing the other file in that same directory), saying that the module (file it is trying to execute) does not exist. I can see that module in that same subdirectory and that subdirectory contains a blank **init**.py file.

I  can not work out what is going wrong here.

EDIT: Atom Text editor even auto-completes the module name when I start typing it..... so it recognizes it as a module

The way I am calling the file is simply

```
from **filename here** import, function1 function2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.